# Schottky heating up

Tags: troubleshooting

I'm having some issues with a [BAT54-7-F](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds11005.pdf) schottky diode heating up. I've asked an initial question over on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/6stnae/hot_schottky/).

Relevant part of my schematic:

[image]

The LED drivers are hooked up according to this schematic:

[image: STCS typical application circuit]

D1 heats up very fast, and gets almost too hot to touch. D1 is in series with R11 (100 ohm). The input voltage is 24V.

I've measured:

- Voltage drop over D1 = ~100 mV (doesn't this seem a bit low?)
- Voltage drop over R11 = 200-400 mV (seems hard to measure, for some reason)
- R11 resistance is within spec

So let's say 400 mV across the 100 ohm resistor, that gives 0.4 mW through the diode. My power supply claims to be supplying 11 mA at 24 V = .264 watts, so there's definitely power going somewhere. There are some other parts on the board, but they should just be taking a few milliamps at 5V, and are not heating up at all. From reddit the two causes of this might be:

- Short to ground after R11, which would cause a ~24 V / 100 ohm = 0.24 amp current. I've measured all over the board and can't find any connection to ground.
- Diode switching losses

Initially I had the µC outputting a ~32 kHz pwm to the drivers, which did cause some noise on the 24V. I disabled the PWM and added a 10 µF cap to the 24V input (though it is quite far from the diode), so the noise I have left now should be from my power supply:

[image]

Is that noise enough to cause switching losses in the diode? And, are those switching losses really large enough to heat the diode up?

The diode has a 5 ns reverse recovery time, which seems fast. And they don't seem to be specifying the reverse recovery charge, so seems I can't calculate the switching losses.

Comment: How are you measuring the voltages across D1 and R11 ? Since there can be a strong AC component, a multimeter might give a wrong reading. A scope is needed and you need to measure differentially so use two probes and look at the difference (there's an option for that on the scope under "Math"). Also you're feeding **two** LED driver chips from only **one** diode + resistor. I'd prefer to keep these separate. So that each IC has its own diode, resistor and capacitor.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I've tried both - though I'm pretty sure I'm not using the math function on the scope correctly, I get very jumpy results (+- 1V over both the diode and resistor). And yeah I figured since the drivers use at most 750 µA one diode and one resistor should do it. They have their own caps though.

Comment: How hot is hot? Please record the temperature when passing thru 10mA.

Comment: The DC current is not the only relevant criterium, it can be that the IC draws current pulses making the voltage across C5, C6 drop which disturbs the other IC. Disconnect one IC and measure if the voltage across C5,C6 is reasonably stable. If there was more than 0.1 V ripple (just my guess) I'd keep the supplies separate.

Comment: @JasonHan Hot enough that I can't keep my finger on it. I noticed now that with the PWM disabled it gets hot, but not hot enough to burn me. I suppose that points to switching losses. I don't have the equipment (yet) for measuring the temperature, only an infrared camera that seems to be showing completely different temperatures and my trusty finger tip.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It heats up even when the circuit is completely inactive, i.e. no pulses anywhere afaik. Though as I just wrote to Jason Han I did notice a difference in temperature with pwm on/off. I figured for my next revision I'll just drive these off of my 5V. Though then I really should put the diode before the voltage reg, where it'll give me the same issues. What's the usual way of dealing with this? Big decoupling cap next to the diode?

Comment: *bypass cap, not decoupling